# Using material design, how to programmatically create a Material Button?

Tags: android, material-design, material-ui

I know how to create a normal button and textview programmtically. However, the documentation for Material design components is a bit lacking. How would I dynamically create a Material Button (and other Material Design components)?

Was referring to the official documentation [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) but it only shows xml creation. Seems like it should be fairly straightforward but I haven't found anything on google / stackoverflow covering this.

Comment: i guess you have to use materialdesign dependency in your project.

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add proper dependency. Check this [link](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) Then you can create it as average view.

Comment: Hi Arthur, I've added the dependency, I guess what I'm not sure about is, do I just create the MaterialButton as follows:  MaterialButton myButton = new MaterialButton(this)

Comment: Yeap. If you need to customize it somehow just use setters with attributes name from xml, for example, button.setText("Some text");